# Use AWS Elastic Transcoder and S3 to stream HLSv4 without making everything public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

I am trying to stream a video with HLSv4. I am using AWS Elastic Transcoder and S3 to convert the original file (eg. *.avi or *.mp4) to HLSv4.

Transcoding is successful, with several *.ts and *.aac (with accompanying *.m3u8 playlist files for each media file) and a master *.m3u8 playlist file linking to the media-file specific playlist files. I feel fairly comfortable everything is in order here.

Now the trouble: This is a membership site and I would like to avoid making every video file public. The way to do this typically with S3 is to generate temporary keys server-side which you can append to the URL. Trouble is, that changes the URLs to the media files and their playlists, so the existing *.m3u8 playlists (which provide references to the other playlists and media) do not contain these keys.

One option which occurred to me would be to generate these playlists on the fly as they are just text files. The obvious trouble is overhead, it seems hacky, and these posts were discouraging: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=529189, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=508365

After spending some time on this, I feel like I'm going around in circles and there doesn't seem to be a super clear explanation anywhere for how to do this.

So as of September 2015, what is the best way to use AWS Elastic Transcoder and S3 to stream HLSv4 without making your content public? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: Reposting my comment below with formatting...**

Thank you for your reply, it's very helpful

The plan that's forming in my head is to keep the converted ts and aac files on S3 but generate the 6-8 m3u8 files + master playlist and serve them directly from app server So user hits "Play" page and jwplayer gets master playlist from app server (eg "/play/12/"). Server side, this loads the m3u8 files from s3 into memory and searches and replaces the media specific m3u8 links to point to S3 with a freshly generated URL token

So user-->jwplayer-->local master m3u8 (verify auth server side)-->local media m3u8s (verify auth server side)-->s3 media files (accessed with signed URLs and temporary tokens)

Do you see any issues with this approach? Such as "you can't reference external media from a playlist" or something similarly catch 22-ish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically generated playlists is one way to go. I actually implemented something like this as a Nginx module and it works very fast, though it's written in `C` and compiled and not `PHP`.

The person in your first link is more likely to have issues because of his/hers `1s` chunk duration. This adds a lot of requests and overhead, the value recommended by `Apple` is `10s`.

There are [solutions](http://www.overdigital.com/2014/06/21/difference-encrypted-hls-phls-hls-drm/) like `HLS` encrypted with `AES-128` ([supported on the Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-transcoder-update-aes-128-encryption-for-hls-content/)), which also adds overhead if you do it on the-fly, and `HLS` with `DRM` like `PHLS`/`Primetime` which will most likely get you into a lot of trouble on the client-side.

There seems to be a way to do it with `Amazon CloudFront`. *Please note that I haven't tried it personally and you need to check if it works on `Android`/`iOS`.*

The idea is to use [Signed Cookies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudfront-signed-cookies-for-private-content/) instead of `Signed URLs`. They were apparently introduced in March 2015. The linked blog entry even uses `HLS` as an example.

Instead of dynamic URLs you send a `Set-Cookie` header after you authenticate the user. The cookie (hopefully) gets passed around with every request (playlist and segments) and `CloudFront` decides whether to allow the access to your S3 bucket or not:

[image: CloudFront Signed Cookies]

You can find the documentation here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's very helpful


The plan that's forming in my head is to keep the converted ts and aac files on S3 but generate the 6-8 m3u8 files + master playlist and serve them directly from app server


So user hits "Play" page and jwplayer gets master playlist from app server (eg "/play/12/"). Server side, this loads the m3u8 files from s3 into memory and searches and replaces the media specific m3u8 links to point to S3 with a freshly generated URL token


So user-->jwplayer-->local master m3u8-->local media m3u8s-->s3 media files


Do you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: It should work, because if I got it right you're serving HLS VOD playlists. The client will download the master and  each variant `m3u8` playlist only once so you need to create them only on playback start or prior (in contrast with Live where you have to do it periodically as it uses a sliding-window). The processing cost will be higher though since you have all the segments in the list. Your load will come in spikes rather than a lower, constant use.

Comment: Here's a similar example but with encryption and for Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-make-token-authorized-aes-encrypted-hls-stream-working-in-safari/